# Where are sys_fork, sys_execve and sys_exit functions in linux kernel 4.10

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

I needed to analyze `sys_fork(), sys_execve(), sys_exit()` kernel functions. I wrote a simple program that calls `fork()` and watched what system calls it uses. There was no `sys_fork()`. I find out that in modern kernel `fork()` calls function `clone()`. And basically it's the same thing with all three functions that i am interested in.

I tried to look at the sources of linux kernel and didn't find any definitions of `sys_fork(), sys_execve(), sys_exit()`. They are defined in headers, but there is no definitions for any architecture.

So my question is: are this functions still used in modern linux kernel, or they were removed and replaced in linux 3.x (I only found this functions in kernel 2.x)?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for unix.SE. The internal implementation of Unix doesn't affect writing programs that use it.

Comment: But it seems like you've answered your own question. These functions no longer exists.

Comment: Look in fork.c. You'll see `SYSCALL_DEFINE0(fork)`, which expands to `asmlinkage long sys_fork(void)`